# Does Caret Train function convert factors to dummy by default in R?

Tags: r, r-caret

I was working with the Palmer penguins dataset with the following code:

```
library(caret)
library(tidyverse)
library(palmerpenguins)

penguins <- penguins[complete.cases(penguins),]
penguins <- penguins %>% select(-year,-island)
set.seed(2020)
indexes <- createDataPartition(penguins$sex, times = 1, p= 0.8, list= FALSE)
train_set <- penguins[indexes,]
test_set <- penguins[-indexes,]

set.seed(1979)
glm <- train(sex ~ .,
             data = train_set,
             method = "glm",
             preProc = c("center","scale"),
             trControl = trainControl(method = "boot"))
```

When I see the coeficients names of the model, I get:

```
glm$coefnames
[1] "speciesChinstrap"  "speciesGentoo"     "bill_length_mm"    "bill_depth_mm"     "flipper_length_mm" "body_mass_g"
```

Is that the variable `species` (a factor) was dummyfied? If so, where is speciesAdelie variable? (there are 3 species: Chinstrap, Gentoo and Adelie).

As requested, I put the summary of the model:

```
summary(glm)

Call:
NULL

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-3.2202  -0.2006   0.0018   0.1655   2.7497  

Coefficients:
                  Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)        0.26369    0.27027   0.976 0.329241    
speciesChinstrap  -3.13336    0.71828  -4.362 1.29e-05 ***
speciesGentoo     -4.84554    1.40355  -3.452 0.000556 ***
bill_length_mm     3.94289    0.83800   4.705 2.54e-06 ***
bill_depth_mm      2.58186    0.69187   3.732 0.000190 ***
flipper_length_mm -0.06028    0.77703  -0.078 0.938166    
body_mass_g        4.99844    0.99530   5.022 5.11e-07 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 370.11  on 266  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 102.84  on 260  degrees of freedom
AIC: 116.84

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 7
```

By the way, the data comes from the package `palmerpenguins` which has a dataset called `penguins`

Comment: Adelie is probably the reference value for the species variable. Can you show the output from summary(glm)?

Comment: Hello @BillO'Brien, I added the output as requested.

Comment: Yes, Adelie is the reference value.

Comment: Do you mean that Adelie acts as the intercept?

Comment: No. Since species is a factor with three levels, the model will return two coefficients: the effect of being Gentoo compared with being Adelie, and the effect of being Chinstrap compared with being Adelie.

Comment: I understand. Do you recommend then to pass the variable `species` to dummyVars function? My doubt is if `caret::train` convert to dummy all factor variables.

Comment: Caret does not encode factors unless specified, however the algorithm called by caret may do so, `glm` for instance does it internally so there is little need to do it manually unless you know exactly why you are doing it and what you want to achieve.